# Can we check the interpreter parameters in node.js app

Tags: node.js

Can I find a way to show the parameters of node.js interpreter like **max-old-space-size** in the node app itself? So that I can show them when I am running the program

Comment: For *max-old-space-size* [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495296/3083470) mentions `v8.getHeapStatistics()`

Comment: What "parameter"? Command line arguments or what are you talking about: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either check [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processargv) if passed as arguments or [`process.config`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processconfig):

> The `process.config` property returns an Object containing the
> JavaScript representation of the configure options used to compile the
> current Node.js executable. This is the same as the `config.gypi` file
> that was produced when running the ./configure script.