# How to confirm that setting --max-old-space-size on the environment variables is actually working?

Tags: windows, npm

After you set your environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS = --max-old-space-size=8192`, how do you confirm that it is now taking effect? Is there a npm command to print the current value? Of course if I just print the environment variable with `echo %NODE_OPTIONS%`, I get the value but that would be different if npm/node itself prints and acknowledges that it is the current value taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=10240' node -e 'console.log(`node heap limit = ${require("v8").getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit / (1024 * 1024)} Mb`)'
```

will print out:

```
node heap limit = 10288 Mb
```

Credit: [@jayseeare and @sam-watkins here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387040/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-max-old-space-size-for-node-js/63495296#comment113451800_62650303)