# Limit RAM usage of Nextjs when run dev?

Tags: node.js, next.js, material-ui, ram

I work in a Nexjs project. It use `@mui/material`.

Follow an issue [appDir + RSC: "The server is running out of memory, restarting to free up memory"](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46756) on github of `Nextjs`.

When I run dev after time, my RAM out.

I only have 8GB RAM on my laptop. When RAM is out, my laptop stuck. I can not do any thing, even move the mouse.

I often press and hold the power button to force power off the laptop.

When I work in an laptop with 16GB ram. The message `The server is running out of memory, restarting to free up memory` show when RAM usage reach about 12GB.

It seem nodejs or Nextjs limit RAM usage. But It is too high with me (8GB RAM).

I want to limit RAM usage of Nextjs when dev. When Nextjs use more RAM which I limited. The progress auto stop or show a message.

When the nextjs use out of RAM. There are small free ram which I can do something like stop nextjs.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes See this V8 options. Or there is memory leak with Next.JS. Or use it like this with env https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495296/14813577.

Answer (score 0):

No issue for me running node js + next js 11/12/13

Asus Zenbook 15 i7 8565u + 16gb ram + 256 SSD + win 11

open vscode with project, then after npm run dev, remaining around 20%

[image: ram after npm run dev]r.com/lQ613.png