How to config nodejs heap size correctly?
I am running a node application with options:  --scavenger-max-new-space-capacity-mb=10240 --minor-ms-max-new-space-capacity-mb=14800 --max-old-space-size=30720 --max-semi-space-size=30720. But I still meet a heap out of memory error like the following shows:
<--- Last few GCs --->
[278585:0x6f76e80]   150225 ms: Scavenge 12098.8 (16428.0) -> 8226.9 (16497.5) MB, 129.54 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   151394 ms: Scavenge 12269.7 (16601.4) -> 8415.0 (16690.6) MB, 143.18 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   153211 ms: Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5) MB, 136.63 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
<--- Last few GCs --->
[278585:0x6f76e80]   150225 ms: Scavenge 12098.8 (16428.0) -> 8226.9 (16497.5) MB, 129.54 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   151394 ms: Scavenge 12269.7 (16601.4) -> 8415.0 (16690.6) MB, 143.18 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   153211 ms: Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5) MB, 136.63 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
<--- Last few GCs --->
[278585:0x6f76e80]   150225 ms: Scavenge 12098.8 (16428.0) -> 8226.9 (16497.5) MB, 129.54 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   151394 ms: Scavenge 12269.7 (16601.4) -> 8415.0 (16690.6) MB, 143.18 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   153211 ms: Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5) MB, 136.63 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
<--- Last few GCs --->
[278585:0x6f76e80]   150225 ms: Scavenge 12098.8 (16428.0) -> 8226.9 (16497.5) MB, 129.54 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   151394 ms: Scavenge 12269.7 (16601.4) -> 8415.0 (16690.6) MB, 143.18 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   153211 ms: Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5) MB, 136.63 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
<--- JS stacktrace --->
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
<--- Last few GCs --->
[278585:0x6f76e80]   150225 ms: Scavenge 12098.8 (16428.0) -> 8226.9 (16497.5) MB, 129.54 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   151394 ms: Scavenge 12269.7 (16601.4) -> 8415.0 (16690.6) MB, 143.18 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
[278585:0x6f76e80]   153211 ms: Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5) MB, 136.63 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.923) allocation failure;
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
 1: 0xcd8bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 1: 0xcd8bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 1: 0xcd8bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 1: 0xcd8bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 1: 0xcd8bd6 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0x10aebf0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0x10aebf0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0x10aebf0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0x10aebf0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0x10aebf0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0x10aeed7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0x10aeed7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0x10aeed7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0x10aeed7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0x10aeed7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 4: 0x12cdeb5  [node]
 5: 0x1301d7e void v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitMarkedObjectsNoFail<v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor>(v8::internal::Page*, v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*) [node]
 4: 0x12cdeb5  [node]
 4: 0x12cdeb5  [node]
 5: 0x1301d7e void v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitMarkedObjectsNoFail<v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor>(v8::internal::Page*, v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*) [node]
 4: 0x12cdeb5  [node]
 5: 0x1301d7e void v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitMarkedObjectsNoFail<v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor>(v8::internal::Page*, v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*) [node]
 5: 0x1301d7e void v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitMarkedObjectsNoFail<v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor>(v8::internal::Page*, v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*) [node]
 4: 0x12cdeb5  [node]
 5: 0x1301d7e void v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitMarkedObjectsNoFail<v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor>(v8::internal::Page*, v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*) [node]
 6: 0x1310e7a v8::internal::Evacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 6: 0x1310e7a v8::internal::Evacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 6: 0x1310e7a v8::internal::Evacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 6: 0x1310e7a v8::internal::Evacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 7: 0x1311332 v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 8: 0x1311757 v8::internal::PageEvacuationJob::Run(v8::JobDelegate*) [node]
 9: 0x1f86538 v8::platform::DefaultJobWorker::Run() [node]
10: 0xeb2401  [node]
11: 0x7b998b694ac3  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
12: 0x7b998b726850  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
Aborted (core dumped)%

The question is, from my option, I already specified the maximum memory usage should be round 30GB, but from the log of Scavenge 12531.2 (16867.3) -> 8650.1 (16956.5), it only around 8GB when it crashed.
Why this happened, what this kind of heap out of memory (FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed) actually means, and which option I can used to let v8 uses larger memory correctly?

Leave new-space (and semi-space) sizes alone (they should only be a few megabytes, no reason to change the defaults), configure the old-space size instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48387040/6036428.

But I also use --max-old-space-size=30720 to set that. The problem is that why v8 crashed too early before it used 30GB of memory?
